# Node.JS - Object outputs {} - why?

Tags: node.js

So I have a few objects such as "friends", "users", "groups" and such that are accessed by using "bot.users" and so on.
But when I try for example:

```
console.log(bot.users);
```

It just returns:

```
{}
```

Why's that? Is it that they're empty or could am I doing something wrong?

Here's documentation on the 'users' property:
https://github.com/seishun/node-steam#users

So if I could help I'd really appreciate it.

Edit; When 'friend' is emitted or whatever, it prints out the current friends. Is it because the 'friends' aren't set before that? How can I make it emit earlier?

Edit2; When 'friend' is emitted, like I already stated, the bot.users is "filled" with "information" as well. (http://puu.sh/7sQsv.png)

Comment: bot.users is an empty object

Comment: An {} means an empty object. You could fake some data by assigning bot.users = {name:'xxx', phone:'yyy'} and then printing it to the console.

Comment: @iandotkelly - Yes, but once 'friends' is emitted, it fills bot.users & bot.friends with information. How could I make it emit it earlier or so, so I get the information filled in as it starts up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you add an event listener and then print?

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop Could you provide the code you're using? We can't help you with timing if we can't see how you're using the lib.

Comment: I had a quick look at the docs, which don't make this very clear .... it seems that the users object is updated when events happen, like friends arriving/leaving etc, so its going to be empty at first.  I think you need to tell us what you are trying to achieve, and post some code.